# getting progress for multiple exec() processes realtime

Tags: php, linux

I have a php script that executes ffmpeg and then it starts working. I can execute this script 4 times and spawn 4 processes. I would like to get progress in real time. How do I get and identify which process is which for each output?

```
$h = fopen('php://stdin', 'r'); $str = fgets($h);
```

I know that line will get whatever output is in stdin but how do you separate it? How do I continuously poll for output? Once a process is started, how do you access that output on a continuous basis? I know you need ajax but what php method will allow you to access that info and separate it from other processes. 
Some have suggested directing output to a text file and getting the contents, but is this the only way? Why keep making more text files for each process? Another suggested redirecting output using `2>&1 | php script.php` after the command. This only gets output at the start of the process since the file executes once.

**I have been struggling with this for a while and am getting closer, so any expert help would be so appreciated.**

**See Edit**

```
$process = exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/cave.wmv -deinterlace -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x320 -f flv /home/g/Desktop/file.flv")
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question.. could you clarify it a bit? Do you feed php with `ffmpeg -o -`? What do you mean identifying the process? You could pass a command line parameter ($argv) to the script so they have a unique identifier.

Comment: sorry see my edit yi. The issue is I am executing a command. I know how to pass variables using $argv. When this command starts, it will start a process of converting a file to another format. If I was to enter that command into a command line, I would get output that shows me the progress of the conversion. I can access this output with $h = fopen('php://stdin', 'r'); $str = fgets($h); in php however the problem is, #1 I do not know how to get output continuously and #2 If I have multiple executions of this process, how can I get each distinct output?

Comment: I mean so lets say you pass a unique parameter and some information initially with 2>&1 | php testing123.php. That information only comes twice for me. It hits the file at the start, and then more comes after the process. I have no idea why. I want to be able to have information all along the way so I can create a progress bar. I am using $h = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

while ( ($str = fgets($h)) !== false )
{

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex. As far as I know exec blocks the PHP thread until it completes. I *think* ffmpeg can write it's progress to a file. You'd need to parse that file to get the progress. You'll want to call that with Ajax.

You need to figure out how you can get ffmpeg to report it's progress, the rest is easy :P

Comment: Yeah that is the problem! I can get it to a file, but would you suggest creating a text file for every upload? I just thought there was a better way, like somehow getting the progress and putting it in a database or something. I am starting to think after banging my head against the wall f**k it, Ill do the text files. I just thought some genius had a better way haha.

Answer (score 0):

If only 4 processes should be running at a time, I really see no reason not to create 4 text files and directing the output of ffmpeg into those. After that it's just a question of reading those text files with PHP.

If you intend to make this HTTP operateable, you could create two scripts: start_process.php and process_status.php. The first file would take an ID as input, starting an ffmpeg process, continuously reading its progress and reporting to a MySQL database. process_status.php would take the same ID as input and report the status from MySQL to the user. You could hook that file up to Ajax and get live updates.

You would have to polish the solution with checking for double entry of the same ID, perhaps automatically creating an ID and returning it from start_process.php etc.

Comment: how do you continuously read the progress though? That is the main issue for me. I really do not want to use text files because much more than 4 people may upload videos.

Comment: Well if you have a unique ID for each process, why not create a folder where you store one text file per process containing it's output? The result would be one PHP process running and monitoring each ffmpeg process by reading its log file.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create an array for the four processes.  Start your processes with proc_open and slap the returned resource in your array.  You could then poll your the array looking at the output for each process resource.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php